# tkz-euclide: incorrect implementation of inversion

Tags: tkz-euclide

The following code should produce a picture of a point and its inverse with respect to a circle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1.3,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){R}
%\tkzDefPoint(1,0){R}
\tkzDefPointBy[inversion = center O through R](A)\tkzGetPoint{A'}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](O,A,A')
\tkzLabelPoints(O,A,A')
\tkzDrawCircle[dotted](O,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However the point and its image are both inside the circle, which is impossible. When I change the radius of the circle to 1.0, I get a correct picture. The implementation of the inverse in the file `tkz-tools-eu-points-by.tex` looks to me as if the radius of the circle is never used, namely the command `\tkzInversePoint(#1,#2)(#3)#4` does not use its argument `#2`. However, this worked correctly in former versions of the `tkz-euclide` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exact it's a bug. I've been strangely modifying this macro. You can rectify it with the following modification which will be in the next update

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\def\tkzInversePoint(#1,#2)(#3)#4{%
\begingroup 
\gdef\tkz@LastList{#4}
    \foreach\PointIP in {#3}{%
      \FirstPointInList\tkz@LastList
      \ifx\tkz@FirstPoint\tkzutil@empty  
         \xdef\tkz@pointtsf{\PointIP '}
      \else
         \xdef\tkz@pointtsf{\tkz@FirstPoint}
      \fi 
   \tkzCalcLength[cm](#1,#2)\tkzGetLength{tkz@lna}
   \tkzCalcLength[cm](#1,\PointIP)\tkzGetLength{tkz@lnb}
    \edef\tkz@lnc{\tkz@lna/\tkz@lnb*\tkz@lna}
   \tkzVecKNorm[\tkz@lnb](#1,\PointIP) 
   }  
\endgroup
} 
\def\tkzUInversePoint(#1,#2)(#3){%  
\begingroup  
   \tkzCalcLength[cm](#1,#2)\tkzGetLength{tkz@lna}% 
   \tkzCalcLength[cm](#1,#3)\tkzGetLength{tkz@lnb}% 
    \edef\tkz@lnc{\fpeval{\tkz@lna/\tkz@lnb*\tkz@lna}}
   \tkzVecKNorm[\tkz@lnc](#1,#3) 
\endgroup
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1.3,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){R}
%\tkzDefPoint(1,0){R}
\tkzDefPointBy[inversion = center O through R](A)\tkzGetPoint{A'}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](O,A,A',R)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,A,A')
\tkzDrawCircle[](O,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]